# Dealing with global variables in modular js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I want to move to a modular approach on a rewrite of a largish js project. And am hoping to use require.js to manage this.

However, I am having some difficulty in understanding how I recode to eliminate global variables.

So where, for example, I previously had

```
var global = 1; //define global
somefunction(); //call function that uses global

function somefunction(){
   var local = global * 2; //use global
   console.log("local = " local); //output
   };
```

and rewritten for require.js

```
define(function(){

   return { 

     somefunction: function() {

         var local = global * 2; //still using global
         console.log("local = " local); //output


         };

      };

   });
```

How would I rewrite this to localize global and make it truly modular.

Comment: Is `global` meant to be used *only* by that module?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `global` is meant to be used *only* by that module, you define it within the `define` callback:

```
define(function(){
   var global = 1;  // <=============

   return { 

     somefunction: function() {

         var local = global * 2;
         console.log("local = " local); //output


         };

      };

   });
```

If you want `global` to be used by other modules, you'd put it in its own module and have modules `require` it. I think with this style of module that means you have to make it an object property (with ES2015 modules, you don't have to).

Comment: Thanks. I guessed as much. And so every module that uses global would have to require it?

Comment: @user3617712: Yup, that's the idea. Make globals effectively obsolete.